# Make project using Maven

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a multi-project (multi-module) Maven project that uses a non-standard DSL compiler. It uses a Maven plugin that runs during Maven's `compile` phase, for just one project in the set.

I tried importing my code as a "Maven" project in IntelliJ IDEA, but IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize that I have a custom compiler for my project; the compile fails.

What I want is to tell IntelliJ, "You can use your normal Java compiler to Make most projects, but for this one project, you should invoke Maven and let it do its thing."

Is that possible?

Comment: Try opening the Maven tool window, select compile, right click and select _Execute before Make_.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I guess that sort of works when I Make, but it doesn't work when I Rebuild. Which is to say, it's clearly running the Maven compile, but the Rebuild still reports compile errors (compiled class not found). I also tried selecting _Execute Before Rebuild_. That ran the Maven compile _twice_ (once before rebuild, and then again before make) but Rebuild still failed with the same errors.